# Outlook CSV to MySQL PHP Class

Tags: mysql, csv, outlook, export

I was wondering if anyone has come across a solid pre-built class for PHP to work with MS Outlook. To have the ability to TAKE a CSV file and import it into a MySQL Database, and also do the reverse export from the database into a solid CSV file to import into Outlook.

If someone has come across something like this, could you possibly share? I haven't had much luck finding anything solid through Google so that would be great!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) if all you need is to export/import CSVs. And it has the benefits of being useful for so many things.

Comment: I want it so the user can upload a CSV file into the system and it import the data.... so I can't use phpMyAdmin....